# printf - Print n and then print a character n times in the next line

Tags: linux, shell, printf, zsh

I have a variable `n`, which is a number, and I'm trying to produce an output like below for `n=10`:

```
10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

So the first line is `n`, and the second line consists of `n` characters, in this example `1`.

I know I can produce the second line with a command line this:

```
$ n=10
$ printf '1 %.0s' {1..$n}
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 %
```

So I can get the output I want with this series of commands:

```
$ n=10
$ printf "$n\n"; printf '1 %.0s' {1..$n}; printf '\n'
10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

But I don't know how I can combine these commands into one `printf` command. The reason for emphasis on being one command is that I'm trying to redirect this output to another command for processing.

I was gonna ask the question on [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), but I saw in the manual of `printf` that it works the same as the one in `C`, so I figured here I might get better results.

> FORMAT controls the output as in C printf.

Comment: The automatic repetition of the format string is a feature only of the shell command, it doesn't come from C.

Comment: `{1..$n}` shouldn't work at all. Variables aren't expanded there.

Comment: @Barmar But it does. Perhaps it's a `zsh` thing.

Comment: That's possible, it doesn't work in `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{}` to group all the commands so you can redirect them all to the next command.

```
{ printf "$n\n"; printf '1 %.0s' {1..$n}; printf '\n'; } | some_other_command
```